# Superset of discriminated union keys

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type which contains all possible keys in the discriminated union (instead of just shared keys)?

If I have a discriminated union, such as:

```
type Form =
  | { name?: string }
  | { name?: string; query: string };

type Keys = keyof Form;
```

Currently `Keys` here resolves to `"name"`, as that is the only shared key, however I'd like it to resolve to `"name" | "query"` (being the superset of all possible keys).

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLZQLwCgpQD5QN5QB2AhkhAPwBcUAzsAgJaEDmUAvpjvkaRdXYxYBuKAEcArhAQh+9JqzZD06UJCgBpCCBpooAay1wAZrERIRAegtQ4hADYgoAY1vBiTHQCISZTwBoiOGAoTwkpEE8gA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type UnionOfKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type Keys = UnionOfKeys<Form>; // "name" | "query"
```

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become *distributive* when given a union type.

`UnionOfKeys` is a conditional type that acts on a generic type, so `UnionOfKeys<T1 | T2>` is equivalent to `UnionOfKeys<T1> | UnionOfKeys<T2>`, which simplifies to `keyof T1 | keyof T2`.